# Maven "conditional" parent POM?

Tags: maven

What's the best structure for a (multi-module) Maven project which should build "in the wild" without any Maven repository manager **and** can easily build within my organization where deployments should happen to my Maven repository manager?

Ideally, I would have two different paren POMs for each situation.
But unfortunately, I can't use a Maven property to pass the correct value for each situation, because the property expression in the parent POM reference doesn't get interpolated, if I try something like

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>${root.pom}</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>
...
<properties>
  <root.pom>wild-parent</root.pom>
</properties>
```

Added a [minimalistic project](https://github.com/m2spring/wild-inhouse-hybrid-example) which shows a crude approach to solve this by patching the parent POM via sed.

Comment: Can you deploy your parent pom to one of the central repositories (such as jcenter or maven-center)?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: The "wild-parent" is part of the codebase.
"my-org-parent" should not be on any public Maven repository.

Comment: I'd like to understand why this question was down-voted. I assume the person never had to make an open source project build in a "corporate" environment where a Maven repository manager is quite typical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This response](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201603.mbox/%3C20160310204059.AC3AD29C1CA3%40dd17332.kasserver.com%3E) on the maven-users mailing list pointed me in the direction to use Maven properties to pass in the in-house specifics.

I updated the [example project](https://github.com/m2spring/wild-inhouse-hybrid-example/tree/property-approach).